# How to apply an ordering to ajax responses

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, each

i use code blow for save html maked with jquery in database and use it later...

```
$('div[read]').each(function(){
    var kelas = $(this).attr('kelas');
    $.post('admin.php',{kelas:kelas,id:id},function(sss){
        alert(sss);
    });
});
```

so its must get from first div to last right?
but its not!
this is image when html maked with jquery  before run each:
http://upbaz.ir/up/2013/12/3533.png
and this  image is from  after run (each) code
http://upbaz.ir/up/2013/12/3534.png
so its not get from first div and then others
how i must apply this?  for each() get from first div and then others to the last div
thank you

Comment: It should be noted that Ajax is _asynchronous_.

Comment: you should make a fiddle, or post your html as well. So we can see the context.

Comment: What is contained within the ajax response by calling admin.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what little can be derived from the question. The problem seems to be that ajax responses are not returned in order. This is to be expected AJAX stands for **Asynchronous** JavaScript And XML.

If you need to impose some ordering there are many ways you can do it. However it looks like there is a number included in the ajax response that corresponds to a div on the page.

Keep in mind the question is very vague so the answer is probably not exactly what the OP wants.

**[For a Demonstration check out the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vTPRa/3/)**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var divs = $('div[read]');

    $(divs).each(function () {

        var kelas = $(this).attr('kelas'),
            id = $(this).attr("read");

        postSimulator('admin.php', {
            kelas: kelas,
            id: id
        }, process(this));
    });

    function process(div) {

        return function (data) {
            // based on the pictures in the question I assume the 
            // a number is returned
            var ord = data.id;
            $(div).append(ord);
        };

    }

    function postSimulator(str, obj, cbFtn) {
        var timeToWait = parseInt( Math.random() * 10000);
        setTimeout(function () {
            cbFtn(obj);
        }, timeToWait);
    }
});
```

The trick to making this work is in the `process` function. Returned from this function is a functions that closes over `div`, when the ajax responses is received postSimulator calls it  and the response is applied to the correct div.

Answer (score 1):

The post() jquery function is asynchronous. You should send all the $('div[read]') object to your admin.php and order the result there before you echo it.

Comment: can you put a example?

Answer (score 0):

i solve it ...
yes post is asynchronous...
so i post in once with code below:

```
var id = ss;
        var kelas = new Array();
        $('div[read]').each(function(){   
            kelas.push($(this).attr('kelas'));

        })
        $.post('admin.php',{id:id,kelas:kelas},function(){
            alert('DONE');
        })
```